# CURL does not return proper error code

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

Here the output is supposed to be anything but 0.

Because 0 according to libcurl documentation is a success. http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050");
```

And clearly curl_easy_setopt is supposed to return 5 i.e CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <curl/curl.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    CURL *curl_handle;
    CURLcode err;
    curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
    curl_handle = curl_easy_init();
    err = curl_easy_setopt(curl_handle, CURLOPT_PROXY, "socks5://127.0.0.1:9050");
    cout << err;
}
```

Am i missing something here ?

Comment: Couldn't resolve proxy sounds like it's just for DNS errors, but you have no DNS name so I wouldn't expected to see it.

Comment: You are just setting the proxy option there ... curl won't try to use it until you actually send a request.

Comment: @LulzAge While often seen in forums, it is **not** appropriate on SO to edit the Q and put "SOLVED" in the title. Please don't do that in the future. Instead, pick the correct answer and mark it as "accepted". That way the information can be processed by the site and be handled accordingly.

Comment: @DanielFrey Oh,Ok.I'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies guys.

I looked "CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_PROXY" on google and came across a few examples.

Turns out i had to call curl_easy_perform(curl_handle) after every curl_easy_setopt to get the error codes.

```
err = curl_easy_perform(curl_handle);
cout << err;
```